# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord

I am trying to call the variable `setInt` which has an anonymous function in my mute.js so I can run a `setInterval` from another file:

```js
module.exports = class MutePlayer extends commando.Command {

    async run(message, args) {
    
        var setInt = function() {
          setInterval(function() {
            //if the current dat in milli >= the milli end time
            if (Date.now() >= dateEnd) {
              //if true then unmute
              message.guild.member(user).removeRole(muted).then(() => {
                message.guild.member(user).send("You have been unmuted!");
                //deleting row with the temp data in it
                let stmt2 = db.prepare("DELETE FROM mute WHERE id = ?", function(err) {
                  if (err) return console.error(err);
                });
                //exe'ing and finalizing data
                stmt2.run(user.id);
                stmt2.finalize();
              });
            } else {
              //if not then show what minute it is and console.log
              counter++;
              console.log("It's not over yet! " + counter);
            }
          }, 60000);
        };
        
    }
}
module.export.module.exports = setInt;
```

Then in another class I try to require and execute it:

```js
var mute = require("../commands/moderation/mute.js").setInt;

mute.setInt();
```

But I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInt' of undefined`

I don't know what I did wrong, maybe I'm supposed to module.exports?

Comment: You're setting the variable `mute` to the `setInt` property of the object you get via `require()`, and then you're trying to reference the `setInt` property of that.

Comment: @Pointy So what is the right way to call the function?

Comment: What you're doing now is effectively `require("..").setInt.setInt()`

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to module.export. module.exports = setInt;

Comment: And since you're getting that error, it's apparently the case that the module does not export a `setInt()` function anyway. Without seeing that code, it's impossible to say why that's the case. *edit* oh wait; you did post it. Then @Antti_M is right: you have to export that symbol.

Comment: @Pointy what code should I show you? I already showed you my setInt function?

Comment: @Pointy I updated my code, I forgot to mention that I am trying to export the setInt function under a module.exports and a async run(). Would that change how I export the function?

Comment: Your `module.exports` assignment looks like it's made **inside** that "run" function. Why? That means the export won't happen until that function is called.

Comment: @Pointy I edited the code but now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`